# Monk db.find not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monk

I am trying to grab an `ObjectId()` out of one of my mongodb fields. The problem is that I know what I am trying to grab is in the db but says it can not be found. I have already verified `token` that I am looking for in the db is working.

Code:

```
var _db = db.get('tokens');
  console.log('token ' + token);
  //token = 587b09875d690d2f4f11849c
  _db.find({'token': token}, function(e, docs){
  console.log('Docs ' + docs);
  if(!e){
    if(docs.length > 0){
      if(expire < phpTime()){
        cb(true);
      }else{
        console.log('Token has expired');
        cb(false);
      }
    }else{
      cb(false);
      console.log('Token not found in db');
    }
  }else{
    cb(false);
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

In the db I have:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId('587b09875d690d2f4f11849d'),
"token": ObjectId('587b09875d690d2f4f11849c'),
"expire": 0
}
```

I keep getting the `console.log('Token not found in db');`. I am really lost on why it is in the db, the token it is looking for are the same but `_db.find` can not find it.

Comment: What are the results if you put `console.log(e)` right before `console.log('Token not found in db');` ?

Comment: `console.log(e)` returns `null`. I make a check in the first if. `if(!e)`

Comment: Oh, obviously, my bad. Does it work if you put the string `'587b09875d690d2f4f11849c'` instead of `token` ?
if it doesn't, please put `console.log(_db)` right after you declare it

Comment: It did not work after I put just the string. So I put `console.log(_db)` and it gave me back crazy stuff. A snippet being 'name: 'tokens',
  options: {},
  oid: [Function],
  opts: [Function: bound ],
  ensureIndex: [Function: bound ],
'

Comment: what is the DB model name?

Comment: Have you used `db.get('dbName')` before?

Also, when you access your db via the mongodb console, is the name of the collection exactly 'tokens'?

Comment: yes the collections name is exactly tokens.

Comment: Can you show us the code for instantiating your mongoose model?

Comment: This is in my app.js file. `var db = monk('localhost:27017/MyDB');`

Comment: I just realized I mislead some people because I forgot I switched to monk a while back. but it is essentially the same.

Comment: What happens if you change your query to `find({}).then(console.log)`?

Indeed, I didn't realize you were using monk.

Comment: `[TypeError: (intermediate value).then is not a function]`

Comment: I mean, `_db.find({}).then(console.log)`

Comment: Yes I did that and it threw that error.

Comment: it should work, according to:
https://automattic.github.io/monk/docs/collection/find.html . 



try `_db.find({token: token}, {}, function(e, docs){`

Comment: it returned back with 
`token 587b09875d690d2f4f11849c`
`Docs`
`Token not found in db`

Comment: Okay, so in my db I changed the token to `"587b09875d690d2f4f11849c"` instead of `ObjectId("587b09875d690d2f4f11849c")` and it worked. I tried earlier to change the token to just that string but it always just adds the `ObjectId()` and I do not know how to get rid of it.

Comment: FWIW: if "token" should be hard to guess (from a security standpoint), you shouldn't be using ObjectId's, which are far from random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, apparently it was not working right when I had an `ObjectId()` in one of my fields I was referencing (token). So I used the code `ObjectId().toHexString()` and stored that into the db so it looked like `5824b9f7611202236ec99c7e` instead of looking like `ObjectId("5824b9f7611202236ec99c7e")`. Hope this helps!